# Play framework 2.4 cannot load image after packaging (404 source not found)

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.4

I've be playing around with Play framework version 2.4 on Windows for while.

The web application works well in development mode, but once I pack it using *activator dist* and run it from another folder, the application fails to load any images, and returns 404 error code to the client. The same thing happens when I am running the app even in ***DEVELOPMENT mode*** on Linux.

Comment: How do you load images? Do you use `Assets` controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, and I feel stupid... Two things I needed to do:

Used the *Assets* controller as Mon Calamari said, and changed the name of image to lower case. Apparently there is something with the case sensitiveness thing going on with Play.